# Google Cloud default-backend is still needed with nginx-ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, nginx-ingress

I made a new project on Google Cloud by enabling the Kuberentes Engine.

Then I installed with Helm v3, *nginx-ingress*.

As far as i see, *nginx-ingress* doesn't create and use anymore the *default-http-backend*.
At the same time Google Cloud create by default a default-backend for the same purpose.

Based on my setup, I think I don't need the Google default-backend Service, Deployment and Pod. Or maybe yes?

Should I delete it?

Comment: What's you ingress implementation? Nginx or default ingress are simply implementation, the K8S definition is the same (except the annotation which customize your implementation)

Comment: I simply installed nginx-ingress through Helm, by following the doc.
As far as i see the l7-deafult-http-backend, has been created during the cluster creation. but if i check it's logs... there is nothing.

Comment: If you use nginx ingress, a L7 load balancer is created but it's a passthrough. The traffic is routed to your nginx ingress pod to enforce your routing rules at cluster level (not at GCP Load balancer level)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i figured out that if you disable the HTTP Load Balancing component from the cluster, the default-http-backend Deployment and Service it will be removed but everything seems to work perfectly. So, that component is responsible for creating  the default http backend, and it will be used ad soon as you work with kubernetes/ingress together with the Google Cloud Load Balancer. Due to the reason i use nginx/ingress the loadbalancer will not interact with the default-http-backend so disabling it is the right choice.